# Why does the logical IFS() function keep getting rendered in lowercase?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, libreoffice-calc

I am dynamically generating XLSX files from java code, and setting the formulas as well. All work fine except for the IFS() function while always seems to render using lowercase "ifs()" and so is not recognized by libreoffice as a function when the resulting file is opened. All other formulas e.g. plain old "IF" work just fine

I've tried debugging into the POI ooxml sourcecode and the last I can tell is that the cell is being set correctly in uppercase. I've tried updating to the latest version, pre-formatting cell contents... no luck so far. This code runs on poi 4.0.1 and I'm opening the file with libreoffice  6.1.3.2 (in case this could be a libreoffice issue?). I don't have access to EXCEL 2016+ to check how that handles the resulting file.

```
public void testIFS(){
    try {
        String IFSformula = "IFS(1,\"yes\",0,\"no\")";
        String IFformula = "IF(1,\"yes\",\"no\")";
        String outputFileName = "IFStest.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet poiSheet = workbook.createSheet("ifstest");
        XSSFRow row = poiSheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
        cell0.setCellFormula(IFSformula);
        XSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
        cell1.setCellFormula(IFformula);
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IFSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Now, cell 0 ends up with =ifs(1,"yes",0,"no") - which is wrong (result is #NAME), but cell 1 works just fine and has a cell formula =IF(1,"yes","no") (result "yes").  If I manually change "ifs" to "IFS" the formula works fine and also shows "yes".

Comment: Not in a position to mock this up locally but just in case this helps - You can perform multiple logical conditions within `IF()`: `IF((1)*(1)*(1),"yes","no")`

Comment: Have you checked that your XML is identifying the file as an Office 2016 .xlsx (supports `IFS`), and not as an Office 2007 .xlsx (does not support `IFS`)

Comment: IFS is not a recognized Function in Excel 2013

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - I know, but that still only allows for 2 results, true and false, I need specifically X possible results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newest `LibreOffice Calc` supports `IFS`. But if it saves `*.xlsx` file then it stores `IFS` formulas using `_xlfn` prefix. Normally that `_xlfn` prefix means [The Excel workbook contains a function that is not supported in the version of Excel that you are currently running.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). So seems that `LibreOffice Calc` tries saving in  `Excel 2016` compatible mode. The [IFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) is from `Office 365` upwards only. And since it stores using that prefix, it seems expecting that prefix while reading `*.xlsx` too.

And even `Office 365` `Excel` stores `_xlfn.IFS` into the `*.xlsx` file instead of only `IFS` (tested today, January 21, 2019). So `LibreOffice Calc` is correct expecting that prefix too.

The following works for me using `apache poi 4.0.1` for creating the `*.xlsx` and using `LibreOffice Calc` (Version: 6.0.7.3 Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)  as well as using `Office 365` for opening the `*.xlsx` then.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class TestIFS {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TestIFS.xlsx")) { 
   String formulaIFS = "_xlfn.IFS(1=0,\"first\",0=0,\"second\")";
   String formulaIF = "IF(1=0,\"yes\",\"no\")";
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("IFStest");
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellFormula(formulaIFS);
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellFormula(formulaIF);
   workbook.write(out); 
  }
 }
}
```